# Circle Animation to a Drawable inside a Custom View in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I have a custom view in which I want to load a drawable and then apply circular animation to this drawable:

```
class Header @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val backgroundPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.YELLOW
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    private val iconRect = Rect()

    private var iconId = 0

    private var iconDrawable: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_app_internal_icon)

    init {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Header)
        val backgroundColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.Header_view_color, Color.YELLOW)

        iconId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.Header_drawer_icon, 0)

        if (iconId != 0) {
            iconDrawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, iconId, null)
        }

        backgroundPaint.color = backgroundColor

        typedArray.recycle()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        drawBackground(canvas)

        drawAppIcon(canvas)
    }

    private fun drawBackground(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.drawColor(backgroundPaint.color)        
    }

    private fun drawAppIcon(canvas: Canvas?) {

        iconRect.top = height / 2 - iconDrawable?.intrinsicHeight!!
        iconRect.left = width / 2 - iconDrawable?.intrinsicWidth!!
        iconRect.right = width / 2
        iconRect.bottom = height/2

        iconDrawable?.bounds = iconRect

        if (canvas != null) {
            iconDrawable?.draw(canvas)
        }
    }

    private fun startAnimation() {
        val animator: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1440f)

        animator.duration = 10 * 1000
        animator.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE

        animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->

            postInvalidate()
        }
        animator.start()
    }
}
```

I know that has something to do with `animator.addUpdateListener`, in there I have to change the coordinates of `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` of the drawableRect. But I don't know how to do it.

the required result is like:

[image]
Any help please?